# Rails - Ruby process sleep when open a file URL and not able to end or kill it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to open a image URL from Activestorage but ruby falls asleep and the last item in console log is:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bfec3dc0d0745e49d7daa9faac7abdeaa46418c3/f2392748480.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-02 14:45:01 -0600
```

and when it ends the error is: `Net::ReadTimeout`

This doesn't happened the first time, but after that it happen each time i run the method.

My method:

```
def upload_photos
  require 'open-uri'
  page_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:access_token])

  image_urls = params[:images].map do |image|
    open("#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{image[:url]}") do |f|
      page_api.put_picture(f, f.content_type, { "caption" => image[:filename] }, params[:id])
    end
  end

  render json: { image_urls: image_urls, album_id: params }
end
```

It works the first time but not after that.

**UPDATE: this works fine with external URLs but not with activestorage**

This is due to Ruby is busy opening the file and when tries to reach the URL is not able to respond to that petition because is opening the file, is like trying to watch your own backhead in a mirror.

Comment: How many threads you're running? Just one?

Comment: Yes, only one .

Comment: In this case, your guess was correct. Run more threads.

Comment: I have done that, but now the issue is how to respond to client with the data.

Comment: I don't think your analysis is correct. Ruby can open multiple files and read from multiple files without issue. Try to store the `f` variable properties in variables without using `page_api` in the `open` block. Then after you close the file, *then* access `page_api` and pass the copies of the file `f` properties. Even make a local copy of the file to a temporary file in `/tmp` if you have to (I don't know what `put_picture` is doing.) This will also separate any issue between Facebook API and `open`.

Comment: @RicardoVillagrana: well, that's another question entirely.